# How to retrieve the instance name of a resource

Tags: puppet

I have a question about Puppet manifests.
When i have the following Puppet resource:

```
apache::vhost {‘homepage’:
…
}
```

How can i retrieve the 'homepage' string from outside the resource?

Comment: Without knowing the title, how to do you plan to even reference the resource? You can get other attributes knowing the title, but without the title it seems somewhat catch-22.

Comment: are you using `puppet apply` or `puppet agent` ?

Comment: im using puppet agent

Comment: @Dotan, the issue Dominic raises with his question is a good one.  I suspect you have an X-Y problem.  In any case, you're unlikely to get any useful answers without providing more context, preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_resources.html) says:

> Resource declarations are expressions in the Puppet language — they always have a side effect of adding a resource to the catalog, but they also resolve to a value.
> The value of a resource declaration is an array of *resource references*, with one reference for each resource the expression describes.

Thus you can write

```
$homepage = apache::vhost { 'homepage': … ; }
```

The value of `$homepage` thereafter will be

```
[Apache::Vhost['homepage']]
```

that is an array consisting of a single resource reference.

---

[Resource references](https://www.Puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_data_resource_reference.html#accessing-attribute-values) can be used to access explicitly defined attribute values.
Thus if you explicitly set the `servername` attribute, the expression

```
Apache::Vhost['homepage']['servername']
```

will evaluate to this attribute’s value.
(You must set an attribute *before* reading it. Setting it *later* will make this expression evaluate to `undef`.)

---

However, the **title of a resource is not an attribute**.
Thus it is not legal to write `$homepage[0]['title']`.
I am stuck at this point, too.
Apparently string interpolation works.
`"${homepage[0]}"` yields the string `Apache::Vhost[homepage]`.
`String.new($homepage[0])` works, too.
You can of course use a regular expression matching whatever’s between square brackets of the string representation, but this is more of a workaround.